# Does Wearable.DataApi.getDataItems users UriMatcher

Tags: wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I'm trying to extract all data from Wearable.DataApi that matches `wear:/someAttr/*`

The motivation is that I'm using [PutDataRequest.createWithAutoAppendedId](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/PutDataRequest#createWithAutoAppendedId(java.lang.String)) since I want to avoid overriding data written in the wearable device.

I would like to match the following URI:

```
wear:/someAttr/3/rand1
wear:/someAttr/2/rand2
wear:/someAttr/3/rand6
```

But avoid

```
wear:/someOtherAttr/3/rand1
```

Can I use wildcard to get data from *DataAPI*?

I have a current workaround of not providing a *URI* to *Wearable.DataApi.getDataItems* which brings all the data but includes unwanted *DataItems* that I would wish to avoid.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution [in a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25430232/android-wear-deleting-data-on-dataapi-with-deletedataitems) by @dzeikei

From Android [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/DataApi)

> int   FILTER_PREFIX   Filter type for getDataItems(GoogleApiClient, Uri,
>   int), deleteDataItems(GoogleApiClient, Uri, int): if this filter is
>   set, the given URI will be taken as a path prefix, and the operation
>   will apply to all matching items.

So in order to match my example you would use

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
builder.scheme(PutDataRequest.WEAR_URI_SCHEME).path("someAttr");
Uri uri = builder.build();
PendingResult<DataItemBuffer> pendingResult = Wearable.DataApi.getDataItems(googleApiClient, uri, DataApi.FILTER_PREFIX);
```